# Django on Elastic Beanstalk - Apache robots.txt

Tags: django, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ec2-ami

I have Django successfully running on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk. I want to serve /robots.txt from Apache instead of via Django. How can I hook into the Apache config to control what Apache is serving?